# Singular Value Decomposition proof - Why does U need to be an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, orthogonality, singular-values

So in the textbook they have the following theorem:

> > [image]

With the following proof:

> > [image]

What I don't understand is why they extend ${\textbf{u}_1, ..., \textbf{u}_r}$ to an orthonormal basis. In fact, if you just define
$$U = [\textbf{u}_1, ... , \textbf{u}_r, \textbf{0}, ..., \textbf{0}]$$

The answer should be the same...? Ie. $U\Sigma = AV$

Comment: So what you're saying is true, but the $U$ matrix you suggest would not prove the theorem, seeing as this $U$ is not orthogonal (since it's not invertible).

Comment: Sorry but why would it matter if it is not invertible? It doesn't seem like it needs to be invertible for this theorem to hold true?

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are invertible... indeed, a matrix is orthogonal precisely when its columns form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @ZoomBee The *theorem* is that there exist *orthogonal* matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $A=U \Sigma V^T$. So in order to prove the theorem, you need to make sure that the $U$ and $V$ you construct are, indeed, orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen to turn my brief comment into a more elaborate answer. If I understand the question correctly, we should really answer why it is interesting that there exists an ortogonal $U$ as opposed to just an arbitrary $U$ that satisfies the equality $U \Sigma = AV$.

First of all, the $U$ suggested in the question is singular, as pointed out in the comments. That choice of $U$ would therefore make the theorem alot more "one-sided" in the sense that you would not have $U^T A = \Sigma V^T$. When both $U$ and $V$ are invertible, the theorem is more "symmetric" and easier to utilize.

Secondly, when both $U$ and $V$ are ortogonal, the singular value decomposition has a nice interpretation. By finding such a decomposition, we can better understand the map $x \mapsto Ax$. Since $A$ is not necessarily neither invertible, nor at all square, it can be difficult to get a grip of what multiplying by $A$ does. The singular value decomposition provides an answer. Since $A = U \Sigma V^T$, we can look at the maps $V^T$, $\Sigma$ and $U$ successively. Here it is really helpful that both $U$ and $V^T$ are ortogonal because multiplication by ortogonal matrices can be thought of as rotations. The multiplication by $\Sigma$ can be thought of as a scaling.

For an even more elaborate answer, please consult the Wikipedia article about SVDs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which explains this interpretation well and provides some illustrative figures and animations.